# Split data into training and test set: How to make sure all factors are included in training set?

Tags: r, training-data

I have a data frame called `b`. I split this into a training set and test set.

```
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(b))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(b)), size = smp_size)
b_train <- b[train_ind, ]
b_test <- b[-train_ind, ]
```

`b` contains a variable/column, let's say `x`, that I use as `factor()` with many different categories.

I use `b_train` to get a linear model with the function `lm()`. After that I use the function `predict()` with the `lm()` object and `b_test`. Unfortunately, `b_train$x`  does not include all different types of characters in `b$x`. Therefore, the function `predict()` can not be used, since `b_test$x` contains categories that are not in `b_train$x`.

How to make sure that all types of categories are included in `b_train$x` ?

Comment: You can create a factor with `levels` same in both the datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done using caret package's createDataPartition() function.

```
library(caret)
samp = createDataPartition(as.factor(b$x), p = 0.75, list = F)

train = b[samp,]
test = b[-samp,]
```